# Get this error when trying to run tensorboard?

Tags: python, tensorflow

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\tensorboard-script.py", line 10, in 
    sys.exit(run_main())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\main.py", line 57, in run_main
    app.run(tensorboard.main, flags_parser=tensorboard.configure)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\program.py", line 228, in main
    self._register_info(server)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\program.py", line 274, in _register_info
    manager.write_info_file(info)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\manager.py", line 269, in write_info_file
    payload = "%s\n" % _info_to_string(tensorboard_info)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\manager.py", line 129, in _info_to_string
    for k in _TENSORBOARD_INFO_FIELDS
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\manager.py", line 129, in 
    for k in _TENSORBOARD_INFO_FIELDS
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\manager.py", line 51, in 
    (dt - datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds()),
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Comment: Please consider adding some specifics, code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

is your tensorboard 1.13.1?
if so,make it come to 1.12.1,solved the problem.
but i can't find out the reason.